# how to use json on mac os

Tags: python

i have encountered a very strange issue: i use json.dump to write a file and then use json.load to read the file.

The same code can run succeed on windows 7 but it can not do on mac os x 10.7
Below is the code:

```
class Result:
def __init__(self,name,result):
    self.name = name
    self.result = result

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Result  name : %s , result : %s' % (self.name,self.result)

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
def default(self,obj):
    #convert object to a dict
    d = {'CaseResult':{}}
    d['CaseResult'][obj.name] = obj.result
    return d


def save(name,result):
    filename = 'basic.json'
    obj = Result(name,result)
    obj_json = MyEncoder().encode(obj)
    with open(filename, mode='ab+') as fp:
        json.dump(obj_json,fp)
        s=json.load(fp)

save('aaa','bbb')
```

in mac os it give an error "ValueError:NO JSON object could be decoded"
who can tell me why this happen and how can i resolve it

Comment: Post your JSON. If the same file works on Windows and not on MacOS my first guess would be character encoding issues.

Comment: Please post your Python code indented. Right now it is not valid Python.

Comment: This ist not a Mac OS X problem. Your initial code throws the same error under Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess the problem lies in how you open the target file. Probably dumping and loading JSON to a file opend in mode 'ab+' doesn't work. Try to dump, close, reopen, and then load the target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is unrelated to being run on a Mac; this code should never work:

```
with open(filename, mode='ab+') as fp:
    json.dump(obj_json,fp)
    s=json.load(fp)
```

This is because after `json.dump`, your file pointer is at the end of the file. You must call [`fp.seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to reset it to the initial position, like this:

```
import os
with open(filename, mode='rb+') as fp:
    fp.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    pos = fp.tell()
    json.dump(obj_json,fp)
    fp.seek(pos)
    s=json.load(fp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this actually works on Windows, but you're missing a seek back to the beginning of the file before you read the object back. change your save/load to

```
with open(filename, mode='ab+') as fp:
    json.dump(obj_json,fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    s=json.load(fp)
```

and it runs just fine on MacOS too. Note that you're appending to the file, so only the first run succeeds in loading the object back, the next one will find extra data after the end of the object.

Comment: @phihag Good point about the extra semicolon, they need a PyLint button for code blocks ;-)